# Why does the getline not execute on second iteration?

Tags: c++, loops, void-pointers

I am trying to change the values of variables repeatedly in the main function using a for loop, the first time it works fine but on the second iteration it skips the `getline` command and goes to the next line. I am still new to programming and not experienced.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getname(string &ss, float &num)
{

    cout << "Type name "<< endl;

    getline(cin, ss, '\n');
    cout << "enter number " << endl;
    cin >> num;
}

int main()
{
    string ss;
    float num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        getname(ss, num);
        cout << ss << endl;
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? What does 'skips' mean? A line of code just **cannot** be deliberately skipped when a compiled code is executed.

Comment: Friendly advice: use either `getline()` or `cin >> variable`, do not mix and match.  See if that solves your problem.

Comment: thank you Mike this solved the problem